# Wamp Server online issue

Tags: colors, server, wamp

I have wamp installed on windows server machine. I started all the services and clicked on Put Online option as well.Then Wamp icon color changed as shown in the attached image [Wamp icon color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5Kyc.jpg). It is not complete green.It has different colors as well.. I was told that green indicates all services online. But what does this color indicates?

Wamp icon color

[image: Wamp icon color]

Comment: it is green ... all service are online

Comment: NOTE: Online and accessable from any IP Address! However if you actually want to access Apache from anywhere you must also port forward your router. **Beware there are dragons out there**

Answer (score 1):

This image [image] indicates that you have set WAMPServer Online i.e. you have used the `Online/Offline` menu and set Apache to be `Online`.

**NOTE:** It is not necessary to have set Apache Online for normal development activity. `Online` only means that Apache can be accessed by any IP Address in the universe.

In other words when Online the `httpd.conf` file contains this parameter in the

```
<Directory "D:/wamp/www/">
```

section on `httpd.conf`

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require all granted
```

when normally it has

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require local
```

Unless you are actually trying to access your site from the internet it is not required to be Online.

Comment: It is not completely green. It is green with a red dot. Can you please suggest what it indicates and what should i do to access it from internet?

Answer (score 0):

Adding Virtualhost section resolved my issue.